# I dont know why the script is not working at all

Tags: jquery, html

```
<script>
$("#myform").submit(function(){

    // Assume there are no error on the form
    var errors = false;

    // Hide all the error messages
    $(".error").hide();

    // Check each field to make sure they're not blank
    if($("#first").val() == ""){
        $("#first_error").show();
        errors = true;
    }

    if($("#last").val() == ""){
        $("#last_error").show();
        errors = true;
    }

    if($("#un").val() == ""){
        $("#un_error").show();
        errors = true;
    }

    if($("#pass").val() == ""){
        $("#pass_error").show();
        errors = true;
    }

    // If there are errors, then show a general error message
    if(errors){
        $("span".text("Oops, ya missed something, try again.").show().faeOut(5000);
          return false;
         }

        // If there are not any errors, show a success message
        $(".success").fadeIn();
        return true;

    });

                    // Make the close button on the success screen work
                    $(".close).click(function(){
$(".success").fadeOut();
});
    </script>
```

Comment: In your errors part you make a call to faeOut().  Should it not be fadeOut()

Comment: Your parentheses and braces aren't properly balanced.

Comment: Ok let me join the typo hunting game... You have a missing closing parentheses where your code says `$("span".text("Oops, ya missed something, try again.").show().faeOut(5000);`. Notice the missing parentheses after `$("span"`?

Answer (score 2):

Your braces aren't properly balanced. You're missing the closing brace for this `if` block:

```
    if(errors){
        $("span".text("Oops, ya missed something, try again.").show().faeOut(5000);
          return false;
         }

        // If there are not any errors, show a success message
        $(".success").fadeIn();
        return true;
    }

});
```

And you're missing a quote here:

```
$(".close").click(function(){
         ^
```

Also, all the code should be inside the `$(document).ready()` function.

Comment: Hey Barmar thanx for your reply but its still not working for me....

Comment: Is it inside `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: No its in  $("document").submit(function()

Answer (score -2):

> $( document ).ready(function() {
>
> ```
>     //your code
> ```
>
> });

Maybe you are missing out the document.ready()